# Curl of an Electrostatic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

According to Maxwell's equations:
$$ \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E} = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$

But if we have an electric field that is dependent upon both the radial distance and angles, we can get a non-zero curl. Does that mean that the rotor of the electric field due to any static configuration of charges, even though sometimes in the form $\vec{E}(r,\theta,\varphi)$ and not just $\vec{E}(r)$, be zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two questions here: can the electric field of a static collection of charges have non-zero curl, and do any electric fields of the form $\mathbf{E}(r,\theta,\phi)$ describe the electric field of a static collection of charges?

As for the first question, for a static collection of charges, the magnetic field does not change with time. Therefore, one has $$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=0$$
Thus, the electric field for a static collection of charges must have a curl of zero; if you write down an electric field with a non-zero curl, that electric field is guaranteed to not be the electric field of any static collection of charges.

As for the second question, yes, there are electric fields dependent on angles that describe physical electrostatic situations. Consider the electric field of a static, charged [tri-axial ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#:%7E:text=An%20ellipsoid%20is%20a%20surface,degree%20two%20in%20three%20variables.); the field here most certainly changes with both $\theta$ and $\phi$, but since it describes an electrostatic collection of charge, the field will have a curl of zero.

Answer (score 1):

A will add some bicycle mechanics to the excellent explanation above.

Unfortunately the Maxwell's equations are burdened by describing something simple required to be valid mathematically in 3D space and time.

An interesting view can be created if the information about a charge present is propagated radially as dots in all directions at the speed of light in the medium.

In the pictures below information is sent as dots at regular intervals in all directions all travelling in a straight line with speed of light in the medium.

Not until the wave of information about a charge has had time to travel to the observer its presence and ability to interact is established.

When an electron moves by, not only does the direction of the field change in intensity and direction, but if the delay in space is considered it adds another dynamic to what field appears and interacts at the observer.

If the dislocation of a charge is slow the environment can be considered up to date and we can use simple straight line geometric distance to the charge and the actual coordinate and speed of the charge as reference.

[image]
A static charge e observed from a pint P

The time derivative of the electric field is zero and will not induce any additionally fields except in the direction the field points.

When speed increases the real world is still bicycle mechanics, it is just the the math do describe the field in 3D space, becomes harder.

In the simple life of a point charge the rules remain the same once it is informed about the vector in particular space and time where it is at.

[image]
The picture illustrates a charge ***e*** moving to the right at constant speed a bit slower than the propagation of information in the media.

The red track illustrates the timing and direction of the "particles" of information from the fly-by, with the communication antenna constantly firing information at point *P*

This gives an intuitive picture of how what it is all about even in relativistic applications. Even though each packet travels in a straight the consecutive delayed information makes the field curve in space-time.

Still bicycle mechanics - it just becomes hard to see when formalized for any point in space.

Finally if you shake an electron periodically back and forth, the density of energy propagating out in space increases with frequency.

[image]
Shaking a charge causes waves.